# How to Install WLK 1.4 on X64 running Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm trying to install WLK 1.4 on Windows Server 2003 running on an 8-core 64-bit machine. I downloaded WLK 1.4 from connect.microsoft.com last week and burnt the ISO. When running KitSetup.exe I get the configuration screen with every option grayed out saying that only x86 is supported. When I go into the DTM directory to try and install the Device Test Manager through the MSI I'm provided another error about trying to install on an x64 architecture when it was compiled for x86.

The installation documents state that x64 is supported and that there should be an x64 directory along with an x86 directory, but neither exist. I've installed .NET2.0 from the ISO from the x64 directory there but I cannot get KitSetup.exe or DTMController.msi to install.

I'm at a loss navigating Microsoft's web site for correct information. How can I get WLK 1.4 installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Install.htm on "System Requirements". The "DTM Controller System Requirements" has a table in which the "Operating System" is specified to be *x86-based* versino of Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) or Service Pack 2 (SP2) installed.

I.e. Although the processor itself can be x64-based, the Server 03 OS must be x86.

Comment: So it does.  I'll install the x86 version then, thanks.